# undo escape of get_theme_mod function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to echo `$loaders_val` variable in PHP. This variable are HTML tag but it's seen like text in the browser.

Which give something like this in the browser:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doqTH.png)

My $loaders_val is being escaped and i found no additional parameter  to passing to get_theme_mod function for output html

Is there a way to output html with get_theme_mod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to hook your theme modification like this:

```
function my_htmlspecialchars_decode($value) {
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($value);
}    
add_filter('theme_mod_my_ser', 'my_htmlspecialchars_decode');
```

Comment: Ismail RBOUH htmlspecialchars_decode change the code in <div class=""loader-inner" ball-zig-zag&quot;="">

Comment: Remove `ENT_NOQUOTES`